# AWS cloudfront url rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS beanstalk application running web-server which generates some static content basing on request parameters. It accepts request urls by following pattern `/image.png?w={width}&h={height}&name={name}`. The application is located behind AWS cloudfront, which caches this content for some short period of time. But I want my content to be publicly available by urls like `site.com/image/{width}/{height}/{name}.png`. Does AWS cloudfront or other services allow rewriting urls like that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AWS Cloudfront support [AWS Lambda Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html). You can use this lambda function to rewrite the URL of request.

However if you store your static content to AWS S3, then you can also do simple [routing configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html)

Comment: Thanks @KaranShah modified this question combing with previous one

Comment: Adding a new answer when the answer is different is completely reasonable AND preferred.

Comment: Thank you @Ashan, that's exactly what I was looking for. I previously found reverse proxied solutions with EC2 and nginx that were a bit overkilled. This one is just right.

Comment: The S3 routing configurations pointer is helpful. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48553470/665224 if you have any issues with multiple query params/ampersands (&) in the replacement prefix.

Comment: @Ashan - I think the simple routing config link has changed. Fairly sure this is the correct link now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: cloudfront functions!

Comment: Note that the redirect, that is supported by aws s3 static websites does not rewrite the url, it just returns a 301 redirect. So the browser will show the url you redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

[Since 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/) you can achieve this with [CloudFront Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html)! They have mentioned it as one of their main use cases. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions.html#edge-functions-choosing) is a comparison with Lambda@Edge

Note that they can be invoked only at **Viewer Request** and/or **Viewer Response** (not Origin Request and/or Origin Response). [Also, make sure to not use any es6 `const`/`let`. You will have to go with es5](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-javascript-runtime-features.html) or you will end up with errors saying `503` `FunctionExecutionErrors from cloudfront`

Quoting the docs

> CloudFront Functions are particularly suited for lightweight and
> short-lived functions, applicable to various scenarios such as:
>
> - **Cache Key Normalization**: Transforming attributes of HTTP requests (such as headers, query strings, cookies, or URL paths) to
>   optimize cache keys, thereby enhancing cache hit ratios.
> - **Header Manipulation**: Ability to add, modify, or remove HTTP headers in requests or responses. For example, adding a True-Client-IP
>   header to each request.
> - **Status Code Adjustment and Content Generation**: Evaluating headers and customizing content to respond to viewers.
> - **URL Redirects or Rewrites**: Directing viewers to different pages based on request information or rewriting requests from one path to
>   another.
> - **Request Authorization**: Validating hashed authorization tokens, like JSON web tokens (JWT), through inspection of authorization
>   headers or other request metadata.

Here is an example function I wrote at `Viewer Request`. Notice I'm returning the modified `event.request`. If you are invoking in `Viewer Response` return the `event.response`

```js
//converts urls like /dev/something/ to /dev
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/$/, '');
    return request;
}
```