# S3 Static website hosting: Is it possible to add multiple query string parameters to the target URL in a redirect rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am currently hosting a static website on S3 which is using redirection rules to re-route the request to a lambda function.

The problem is I have two buckets that are both acting as static websites (sandbox vs production) and I need to be able to point them to the same lambda function *but be able to tell them apart* when the function is run. Whether it's a header, a `GET` parameter, string manipulation, anything I can use to determine which bucket the request came from.

Does anyknow know how inside the lambda function I can identify that the request came from one bucket over the other? This is the current redirect rules I am using:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
     <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>removed.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/func?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

From what I understand I cannot set and headers or `GET` parameters from this routing ruleset as the validation for the rules fails and my only option as it stands is to duplicate the lambda function, which I really don't want to do as it feels verbose.

I have also done `JSON.stringify()` on the `event` & `context` parameters within the Lambda function and cannot seem to see any item to help me uniquely identify the origin bucket.

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add query string ("GET") parameters, you have to remember that this is an XML document, which requires escaping `&` → `&amp;`.  S3 will still render the query string correctly in the redirect with this approach.

Invalid:

```
<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/func?foo=bar&buzz=fizz&key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
```

Valid:

```
<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/func?foo=bar&amp;buzz=fizz&amp;key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
```